# Regex match string with at least one uppercase and at least one number from 0-9

Tags: regex

I am having a problem with the regex expressions. I am trying to match a string, which should contain at least one uppercase charracter and at least one number from 0-9
Lets say we have these strings:

```
   sdsFg3n match
   asdfghf not match
   aewag3t not match
```

The order of the charracters and numbers is not important.. The string should just contain them. The expression I tried is `[A-Za-z0-9]`, but that doesn't help me...

Comment: `^(?=.*[A-Z]).*\d.*`.... Next time, you should post your attempts.

Comment: Wow, that was quick.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't think we should encourage this kind of questions; Your solution doesn't really help OP understanding how to solve problems in real life.

Comment: @ВасилЕмилов could you reproduce your comment?

Comment: @MarounMaroun see his attempt.. :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj  your regex failed to handle number after upper case :-)

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley where he mentioned? I saw only atleast one digit and atleast one upper case.

Comment: @ВасилЕмилов post an example where my regex failed to handle?

Comment: @ВасилЕмилов Actually this looks pretty neat for that it came out of a head in less than a minute. It uses an initial lookahead to check for an alpha `^(?=.*[A-Z])`. If succeeds, it matches all string `.*\d.*` requiring at least one digit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, but what you did is different. you have introduced the happen before relationship between upper case and number

Comment: @AvinashRaj since you updated your first comment.. the expression works as needed.. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why there is a '-' on my question though...

Comment: @bobblebubble "Wow, that was quick.", because I'm doing the same thing again and again.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I understand, I'm still impressed. The first posted worked flawless and pattern did not change on edit. When comment was edited there was just added some text. I had pasted it in regex101 and it did not change. Why not post an answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble exactly, I didn't change the pattern . I just added the text `Next time,`

Comment: `Why not post an answer?`, this is a simple question which lacks attempts..

Comment: @AvinashRaj my apologies then... I guess I should've copied it wrong :)
As a quick update.. How can I exclude the other symbols beside numbers and letters.

Comment: @ВасилЕмилов based on Avinash regex, if you want to allow only alphas and digits, [see demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uS9cJ4/2). Try `^(?=.*?[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z\d]*$`

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple, like this?

```
([A-Z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[A-Z])
```

Comment: This solution works for me, here a sample implementation `/[A-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Z]/.test('Hotch1')` this return `true` if instead of `Hotch1` you try 'hotch1' the result is `false`. Thanks